# Sorting an ArrayList based on a class data member's data member

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

So, I have a class which contains another class object as its data member. I have created an ArrayList based on this prototype. Here is the code:

```
    package Stack;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


    class Point
   {
       int x;
       int y;

       Point(int x, int y)
       {
           this.x = x;
           this.y = y;
       }
   }

   public class MergeInterval
   {

       Point P;

       MergeInterval() {}


       public static void main(String args[])
       {
           ArrayList<Point> arr = new ArrayList<Point>();
          // Point p = new Point(6,8);

           arr.add(new Point(6,8));
           arr.add(new Point(1,9));
           arr.add(new Point(2,4));
           arr.add(new Point(4,7));

        //   System.out.println(arr.get(1).x + " " + arr.get(1).y);

       }
   }
```

I need to sort this Arraylist as to get the output as following:
{1,9} {2,4} {4,7} {6,8}

Basically I needed to sort this structure based on the 'x' variable of Class 'Point' but using the inbuilt 'sort' method. How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`List.sort(...)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) takes a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which determines how the elements in the list should be compared to each other for the purposes of determining the order. You can either implement `Comparator` yourself to specify that the `Point`s should be compared by comparing their `x` values, which takes several lines of code, or you can use one of the built-in `Comparator`s.

The `Comparator` interface defines default implementations for the case where you want to compare via something that is a simple function of the list element.

Since you are comparing on an `int` property, you can use [`Comparator.comparingInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) as follows:

```
arr.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.x));
```

Comment: That helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be if your Point class implements Comparable. Processes like sorting require some kind of comparisons to happen. Please take a look at this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/).

In this case, your Point class would implement Comparable. For this to work, your Point class would also require a compareTo(Point other) method. In your case, this function would return 0 if this.x == other.x, -1 if this.x < other.x and 1 otherwise.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Why does `Point` need to be comparable? The OP wants to order them by the `x` value, which is an int.

Comment: Isn't it an ArrayList of Point objects that needs to be sorted?

Comment: Yes, but the ["built in" `sort` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) takes a `Comparator`. There's no need for `Point` to be `Comparable`.

Comment: Yes, I was just offering an alternative solution, to better explain the concept, since it seemed like the OP wasn't aware of Comparable. Clearly, your answer is a much slicker solution.

Comment: So say that. Your answer is full of statements that are simply not true: "Your Point class would need to be Comparable": it doesn't "need" to do anything of the kind.

Answer (score 0):

Create a comparator like this:

```
Comparator<Point> comparator = new Comparator<Point>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Point o1, Point o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1.x, o2.x);
    }
};

arr.sort(comparator);
```

You can add this code after you have populated the list.

Comment: It works, but it's a bit old school and more verbose than it could be.  Very often in Java 8, the idiom of choice for sorting with a `Comparator` is to pass a lambda expression to the method.  Anonymous inner classes are so, so very ... Java 5.